# Access Single JavaScript Object for multiple node.js files?

Tags: node.js, nodes, javascript

I've been trying to use a Single JavaScript object in multiple files. For that I chose singleton design pattern in JavaScript.

**mySingleton.js**

```
var mySingleton = (function () {
var instance;
function init() {
function privateMethod(){
    console.log( "I am private" );
}
var privateVariable = "Im also private";
var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();

return {

  publicProperty: "I am also public",
  publicMethod: function () {
    console.log( "The public can see me!" );
  },

  getRandomNumber: function() {
    return privateRandomNumber;
  }

  };

};

return { 

getInstance: function () {
  if ( !instance ) {
    instance = init();
    console.log("Newly creating an object");
  } 
  return instance;
} 
};
})();
module.exports = mySingleton;
```

And i'm Accessing the The above object in a separate node js file. As showed in following code

**test.js**

```
var singleton = require('./mySingleton');
var obj = singleton.getInstance();
console.log(obj.publicProperty);
console.log('random number value:'+obj.getRandomNumber());
```

**test2.js**

```
var singleton = require('./mySingleton');
var obj = singleton.getInstance();
console.log(obj.publicProperty);
console.log('random number value:'+obj.getRandomNumber());
```

When i execute the above two files each time a new javascript object is creating. But I want to use the same JavaScript object in multiple files.

Thanks in advance....

So Can anyone please give any suggestion to achieve the above functionality.

Comment: You should remove the `java` tag. Java is a programming language that  has nothing to do with Javascript :)

Comment: are you using any framework, like Express 4.0?

Comment: are you executing test.js and test2.js independently one by one?

Comment: Are you doing `node test.js` then running `node test2.js`?

Comment: No @Datsik i'm not using any framework like express, I'm using in just plain node js file. Yes i'm doing as like this "node test.js then running node test2.js".

Comment: See my answer down below

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are running test.js and test2.js independently.
When you execute test.js, it creates a global context where `obj` binds to global scope of test.js.
After the execution is complete, that context is destroyed and a new context is created for test2.js. Hence the `instance` variable inside `getInstance` function does not find the instance and creates a new one.
To correctly use single pattern you need to use same `singleton` variable to get instances.

Thus once you have created `singleton` using

```
var singleton = require('./mySingleton');
```

you need to get all the instances using this variable only. Since the singleton property is arising due to closure of execution of anonymous function which returns object to `mySingleton`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling them individually which will not work, every time you call node test.js you're creating a new run time variable:

If you were to include them into a main package and run it, you would see that it works just fine:

[image]